# nanosleep - need low resolution

Tags: cpu-usage

We are running both SLES10 (2.6.16.60-0.54.5-smp) and SLES11 (2.6.32.12-0.7-default).

After 2.6.16, nanosecond was changed to make use of high resolution timers.
Our code must run with similar characteristics on both SLES10 and SLES11.  Currently because the SLES11 kernel is configured for high resolution timer (which we may not change), we find CPU usage is much higher than on SLES10.  A simple looped nanosecond sleep will display in "top" on SLES11, where not on SLES10.

We can change the calls to nanosecond in the code, but don't know what to change to make them work equivalent on both platforms.

More info:
on SLES11, kernel timer interrupt frequency is approx. 4016 Hz or higher
on SLES10, kernel timer interrupt frequency is approx. 250 Hz

what value should be used in timespec's tv_nsec to decrease CPU usage on the SLES11 platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous behaviour (sleeping for a nanosecond with a 250Hz interrupt frequency) would, in average, sleep for 1/500th of a second.

If you want approximately the same behaviour as before, you can simply sleep for 1/500th of a second, which is 2,000,000 nanoseconds.